# Как быстрее возводить число в степень?

Tags: c#

В степень поднимать можно некоторыми способами, тут нам интересуют две - `Math.Pow` и умножение в цикле (для 2 степени не надо цикл). Какая из этих работает быстрее когда

1. степень равна 2
2. степень больше 2 и теоретически стремиться к бесконечности.

---

Есть какая-то граница где до этого умножение работает быстрее, а после - `Math.Pow`, или наоборот?

---

П.Н.
Степень должен быть **натуральное** число.

Comment: Как вы собираетесь в цикле возводить в степень 2,17?

Comment: Поясню. Например у меня переменная `a`. Для квадрата можно без цикла, то есть `a*a;`. А для степень > 2 используем цикл - `for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){ result *= a; }`

Comment: Хорошо, как с помощью цикла вы посчитаете a^2,17? Вы ведь знаете, что степень может быть не обязательно натуральным числом?

Comment: @АндрейNOP должен натуральным быть. Сейчас исправлю в вопросе

Comment: Можно замерить самому, кто быстрее. Но вообще-то на десктопе степень вычисляет сопроцессор и делает это довольно быстро.

Comment: Хорошо, гуглите "быстрое возведение в степень", оно уже быстрее чем O(n), так что стоит ожидать, что библиотечная функция не будет реализована медленным способом

Comment: @АндрейNOP хорошо. Быстрые способы я понял. Но если возвращаться к вопросе. Мне больше интересует существует ли такая граница о котором я говорил сверху?

Comment: Для степени 4 надо сделать столько же умножений, как и для степени 3. Для степени 1024 надо всего то 10 умножений. А для 7 степени надо 3 умножения и деление. То есть просто циклами вы тут точно не отделаетесь :) а вообще, если бы я одно и то же число часто возводил в степень, я бы степени заранее закешировал, и результат бы получал мгновенно (так, например, делают с таблицами синусов/косинусов иногда в играх). То есть ваш вопрос сильно от контекста зависит.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обычно степень, в которую возводится число, не будет слишком большим. Например, .NET позволяет поместить в `double` результат `3^646`. Дальше результат воспринимается как бесконечность. Если тестировать производительность возведения степени с помощью цикла и с помощью библиотеки Math, то ощутимой разницы вы не почувствуете. И то и то вычисляется менее чем за милисекунду. Однако если считать количество тиков процессора, то цикл немного выигрывает за счет того, что библиотека Math позволяет возводить в вещественную степень (`double`), из-за чего возведение в целочисленную степень будет не самым оптимальным.
На моем процессоре для вычисления `3^646` результаты получились следующими:

> *Math lib pow*: **350-450 ticks**
>
> *Manual   pow*: **250-400 ticks**

Тестирующий код:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    const double number = 3;
    const int pow = 646;

    /*
    var watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    var powResult = Math.Pow(number, pow);
    watch.Stop();
    */

    var watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    var powResult = 1.0d;
    for (var i = 0; i < pow; i++)
    {
        powResult *= number;
    }
    watch.Stop();

    Console.WriteLine($"Pow result:   {powResult}");
    Console.WriteLine($"Time execution: {watch.ElapsedTicks} ticks");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Я попробовал ради интереса. Расхождение начинается прямо уже с первых степеней и дальше всё довольно линейно.

```
import time
import math
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pylab as plt
%matplotlib inline

def timeit(method):
    def timed(*args, **kw):
        ts = time.monotonic()
        for i in range(100000):
          result = method(*args, **kw)
        te = time.monotonic()
        return (te - ts)
    return timed

@timeit
def pow_by_mul(x, y):
  s = x
  for i in range(y - 1):
    s *= x
  return s

@timeit
def pow_by_asterisk(x, y):
  return x ** y

@timeit
def pow_by_math(x, y):
  return math.pow(x, y)

k = 13
n = 13
df = pd.DataFrame({'pow_by_mul': [pow_by_mul(k, y) for y in range(n)], 'pow_by_asterisk': [pow_by_asterisk(k, y) for y in range(n)], 'pow_by_math': [pow_by_math(k, y) for y in range(n)]})

df.plot();
```

[image: График скоростей работы функций в зависимости от степени]

По горизонтальной оси - степень, в которую возводим. По вертикальной оси - время в условных единицах.

- pow_by_mul - возведение в степень умножением
- pow_by_asterisk - возведение в степень с помощью оператора Python **
- pow_by_math - возведение с помощью math.pow

**P.S. *У меня сейчас два рабочих языка: Python и C#, и я, кажется не в тот раздел написал. Если это не в тему, я могу снести ответ. :)***

Comment: Это полезно знать, но как ваш ответ относится к c# ?

Comment: @tym32167 Ойой. У меня два рабочих языка, кажется, я начал в них путаться ((

Comment: @CrazyElf для питона понятно, для шарпа не совсем. Но вы на всякий оставляйте ответ, как никак лучше чем ничего

Comment: Может это и не шарп, но вычислительную сложность объяснил доходчиво. К чему лишние придирки?

Comment: @ЖекаДиулин, а где объяснение вычислительной сложности?